# Adding Sharepoint list column that is populates dynamically from items

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have a SharePoint list that has a bunch of colunms. I need to ad an additional column. This column needs to be populated with the numbers of the items in the list, i.e. 1 - n-th.

I'm not sure how one would do that. Would I need to create it using simple SharePoint or using SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 0):

There already *is* such a column — `ID`. It's automatically assigned from a counter. However, when you delete an item, a gap in numbering emerges.

And no, you probably can't create a similar but custom column using plain SharePoint or SharePoint Designer. You would need to create an [event receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.aspx) do assign the values programmatically.